# How to make jquery knob readonly using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I'm using a jquery knob plugin. I want to make the knob readonly on button click.

```
(function() {
$(".dial").knob({
    'min':0,
    'max':360,
    'change' : function(degree){
        var img = $(".volume_bttn");
        if(radioSwitchState == 1)
        {
            img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            var vol = ((degree)/360).toFixed(2);
            //console.log(vol);
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("volume",(360-vol));
        }
    },
    'fgColor' : '#460E09',//460E09
    'bgColor' : "transparent",//transparent
    'width' : 107,
    'thickness' : 0.3,
    'displayInput' : false,
    'linecap' : 'butt'
    });
});
```

This is a code where I'm initializing the knob. How to make it readonly on button click?(I repeat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery Knob Documentation](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob):

```
$('.dial').trigger(
    'configure',
    {
        "min":10,
        "max":40,
        "fgColor":"#FF0000",
        "skin":"tron",
        "cursor":true
    }
);
```

So you would end up with something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.dial').trigger('configure', {"readOnly": true});
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks good, but not going through when going for on document ready it doesn't works, any idea, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Looking into the code you cannot use the `$('.knob').trigger('configure', {})` to set the readOnly state after the knob has been created. The reasons for this is because "configure" event is bound to:

```
var cf = function (e, conf) { 
    var k;
    for (k in conf) {
        s.o[k] = conf[k];
    }
    s._carve().init();
    s._configure()
    ._draw();
};
```

As seen in this function, these are the only methods called. The "readOnly" option is only looked at once from what I can see when the knob is first created so changing this value after calling `$('.knob').knob();` doesnt work.

You must set this value during creation:

```
$('.knob').knob({
    "readOnly":true
 });
```

Comment: I can confirm this is correct. Setting it on creation works, but trying to set it using configure does not. This should be the correct response.

Answer (score 1):

See if the trigger approach posted by @dodo works. If not, I've got two workarounds:

1. Attempt to unbind all of the relevant events (click, scroll, mouse down  up etc)
2. Create a **blank div** with the same dimensions as your knob and **overlay it** above the knob. You will still see it, but all events will be caught by the div, making your knob 'readonly'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dial").knob({
    min: 1
    max: 10
    stopper: true,
    readOnly: true,//if true This will Set the Knob readonly cannot click
    release: function (value) {
      //Do something as you release the mouse
    }
})
```